# Antiderivative of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to find a function $f(x_1,x_2)$ such that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} = \frac{ax_1+bx_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}$$ and $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = \frac{bx_1+dx_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}.$$

I am able to find $$\int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} dx_1 = a\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2} + bx_2\log(\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}+x_1)+G(x_2)$$ and $$\int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} dx_2 = d\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2} + bx_1\log(\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}+x_2)+H(x_1).$$ From here I really don't know where to go.

Comment: There is not such $f$ unless $a = d, b = 0$. For general $a, b, d$, 
$\displaystyle\;\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\frac{ax_1 + bx_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}} 
\ne
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\frac{bx_1 + dx_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}\;$.

Comment: achille hui is right, you need $a=d$ and $b=0$, if this is the case, you can get $G_{x_2}(x_2)$ by solving for it in the equation: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} \int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \mathrm{d}x_1=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}$$